# Docker Windows - Looking for Ubuntu command in bash location

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker

New to docker.  Downloaded DockerToolbox-1.10.2.exe and installed on Windows 7, appears to be running properly.

Trying the hello world tutorial at:

[Hello World at Docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerizing/)

When I run the following command

```
$ docker run ubuntu /bin/echo 'Hello world'
```

It appears to download the Ubuntu image:

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
5a132a7e7af1: Pull complete
fd2731e4c50c: Pull complete
28a2f68d1120: Pull complete
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4e85ebe01d056b43955250bbac22bdb8734271122e3c78d21e55ee235fc6802d
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
```

but then I get a the following error message:

```
exec: "C:/devel/Git/bin/echo": stat C:/devel/Git/bin/echo: no such file or directory
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist
```

That path is where I'm running bash.exe in Windows from to run docker.  I'm sure this must be a configuration problem, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a PATH which has `c:\devel\Git` in first, before the rest, making the shell to call the wrong echo.
Try changing that order (`set PATH=...;c:\devel\Git`).

Make sure you connect to your machine first:

```
docker-machine ssh
```

Then you can try again your docker run command

Comment: docker-machine ssh did the trick.  I must have missed that step.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @javatestcase no problem. I have found that, on Windows, all I need is docker-machine (copied from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases). I don't even bother with docker toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Escape the unix-style path in your command with a `/`. The following works.

```
$ docker run ubuntu //bin/echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
```

---

### Longer Answer

The **reason behind this behavior** seems to be that Git Bash (which is based on MinGW64 / [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/Home/)) tries to do some smart **path conversion** when it finds unix-style paths. I only found the source code for the conversion (I believe [here](https://github.com/Alexpux/path_convert)), but no documentation. The only documentation I found on this was for [MSYS1 path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion), which should be similar.

Let me quote [MSYS1 path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) by screenshot. You see from the example that a "unix-style" path like `/bar` will be re-written as a relative path to MSYS2 root directory (i.e., the Git directory in case of Git Bash), while an escaped path like `//foobar` is passed as is.

[image: MSYS1 path conversion examples screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker run ubuntu //bin/echo 'Hello world'`